# How to get git diff in vim when writing a commit message?

Tags: filetype-git

This may be a weird question, because I already have this setup in my dotfiles somewhere, I just don't know how to tell a friend to set it up in their dotfiles.

I want to know how to get a nice git diff displayed in your gitcommit file, whenever you compose a git commit message with vim. Here are [my dotfiles](https://github.com/aharris88/dotfiles) if that helps. I couldn't find the answer online and it was hard to search without knowing what to search for.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This behavior seems to come from calling `git commit -v` or `git commit --verbose`. Not sure where you're doing that in your dotfiles, but I'd recommend telling him to set an alias in his git config that does that.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it comes from the aliases that oh-my-zsh provides: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet#helpful-aliases-for-common-git-tasks

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, Do try out [committia.vim](https://github.com/rhysd/committia.vim), a plugin for writing a commit message. When `git commit`ing, it splits the window and shows the diff and status window very nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use Tim Pope's [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). It provides `:Gcommit` which is a wrapper around `git commit` (So you can do `:Gcommit --verbose`).

Probably the more preferred way would be to use `:Gstatus` and execute `cvc`. Then just create your commit message and then save and quit (I use `:x`).

For more help with fugitive.vim I recommend Vimcasts episodes mentioned in this article: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/).

For more help see:

```
:h :Gcommit
:h :Gstatus
```